# Physical systems where behavior is different when setting parameter exactly to zero

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Are there any physical systems that express a certain behavior (e.g. long range order) even when some parameter limits to zero , $\lambda \to 0$, but do not have that behavior when that term is not present: $\lambda = 0$.

Is there a name for such property of physical systems?

Comment: Such a thing is generally some flavor of instability, since you're saying that arbitrarily small $\lambda$ has a qualitative effect that is not present when $\lambda=0$. Or it can be a dissipation (and dissipation is not always the same thing as "instability in negative time"). In practice both instability and dissipation tend to have some associated time scale which blows up as the intensity of the perturbation goes to zero (and on times shorter than that scale, the perturbation is insignificant).

Comment: Steady-state solutions would be different for a very small but finite lambda and lambda exactly zero. Say, you have a collection of molecules. If the collision rate is nonzero then the steady-state velocity distribution will be Maxwellian, otherwise not. Of course, to reach the steady state it will take longer for a smaller collision rate.

Comment: The question, in its present formulation, looks too broad to allow an answer not equivalent to a list of cases.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a phenomenon called stochastic resonamce

Comment: @GiorgioP can you list a few cases? It may help me look into it and search.  I have a notion that this is a relatively generic concept in statistical mechanics -- not stochastic resonance -- and it is on the tip of my tongue.

Comment: Maybe are you thinking to spontaneous breaking of symmetry? However in that case, in addition to the breaking symmetry field which goes to zero, there is a thermodynamic limit which plays a key role.

Comment: Quantum electrodynamics is (I think) nonrenormalizable for any finite photon mass, no matter how small. Then, at $m=0$, it becomes renormalizable.